# Short circuiting if statement

Tags: c, if-statement, short-circuiting

Say you have this nested if-statement:

```
int *x;
int y;
if (x == NULL || y > 5)
{
  if (x != NULL)
    // this should print if x != NULL and y > 5
    printf("Hello!\n");
// this should only print if x == NULL.
printf("Goodbye!\n");
}
return 0;
```

Here, if either statement is true, it will return the same value (0). We should only print "Goodbye" if the left side of the outside if statement is true, regardless of whether the right hand side is true or false. Is it possible to eliminate the inside if-statement by short-circuiting, turning this into a single if-statement?

Comment: The short-circuiting behavior does not change anything in this specific case. Your question is not clear.

Comment: The comments in the code imply that there should be an `else` before the second `printf()`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'll edit my question. I am curious whether I can eliminate the inside if-statement all together by short-circuiting.

Comment: @user12787203 You should write your code in a way that is clear and easy to understand and leave the optimization to the compiler.

Comment: Aside: the code has undefined behaviour anyway because you are reading values that have not been initialised.

Comment: By "short-circuiting" you can eliminate `if`s completely: `(x==NULL && printf("Goodbye!\n")) || (y > 5 && printf("Hello!\n"));`. Not that I encourage this style.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly what you need is the following

```
if ( x == NULL )
{
    printf("Goodbye!\n");
}
else if ( y > 5 )
{
    printf("Hello!\n");
}
```

Otherwise if the first compound statement includes other statements that have to be executed in case when x == NULL or y > 5 then the if statements can look like

```
if ( x == NULL || y > 5)
{
    // common statements that have to be executed when x == NULL or y > 5
    //...
    if ( !x )
    { 
        printf("Goodbye!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Hello!\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only print Goodbye if x is NULL and y > 5

```c
if (x == NULL || y > 5)
{
  if (x != NULL)
    // this should print if x != NULL and y > 5
    printf("Hello!\n");
  else
    // this should only print if x == NULL.
    printf("Goodbye!\n");
}
```